# Can required if in vue props?

Tags: vuejs2

Can Vue.js set required props by another props variable.

## Ex.

```
props: {
    data: {
        required: this.writeable,
        type: Array
    },
    writeable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
},
```

In this case. I want to set `data` required ot not by `writeable` value.

If `writeable` was not set or set as `true`, You must to pass `data` to this component. And If `writeable` set at `false` the component will not require `data`.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done.

As a workaround, you can validate manually using [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

```js
  watch: {
    writeable: {
      handler(value) {
          if(value && typeof this.data === 'undefined') {
              console.error("property 'data' is required. ")
          }
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
```